# PHP Guzzle: Mock a curl exception / cause a CurlException to be thrown in tests

Tags: php, guzzle

Using the [Guzzle HTTP client library in PHP](http://guzzlephp.org/) I can use the [mock plugin](http://guzzlephp.org/guide/plugins.html#mock-plugin) to mock HTTP responses and to choose the HTTP responses to be returned deep within application code.

Guzzle might throw a [CurlException](http://guzzlephp.org/api/class-Guzzle.Http.Exception.CurlException.html) when attempting to send a HTTP request.

Using Guzzle, how can I mock curl exceptions, or how can I cause a CurlException to be thrown deep within application code?

Answer (score 0):

A recent addition to Guzzle was this very feature: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Plugin/Mock/MockPlugin.php#L149

Just use the MockPlugin and the `addException()` method to queue a CurlException exception.